# Getting array of objects from database using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to download comments from database and display them on my page. Current code returns syntax error as php file does not return proper json file.

My php code (no connection problems so only fetching part).

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0){

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo json_encode(array(
            "id" => $row["id_com"],
            "nick" => $row["com_nick"],
            "email" => $row["com_email"],
            "text" => $row["com_text"],
            "data" => $row["com_data"],
            "ocena" => $row["ocena"]
        ));
    }
```

Returned value.

```
{"id":"1","nick":"my_nick","email":"g@go.pl","text":"content!","data":"2016-08-03","rate":"5"}{"id":"4","nick":"ra","email":"hat@gon.ha","text":"Hat","data":"2016-08-03","ocena":"1"} ect...
```

Ajax request (I think problem lies here)

```
$.ajax
    ({
        url: "/commdown.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
              alert(  

                      "id: " + data.id +
                      "\nnick: " + data.nick +
                      "\nemail: " + data.email +
                      "\ntext: " + data.text +
                      "\ndata: " + data.data +
                      "\nocena: " + data.ocena

              );
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        { 
            alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
        }  
    });
```

I think the problem is that I'm downloading multiple objects with single ajax request instead of calling a request for every comment separately.

Comment: Could you quote the error message?

Comment: You are returning multiple JSON Objects instead of one which creates invalid JSON. Gather them in your while and do one `echo json_encode();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a array to append all the data to it then echo that encoded data, use a loop in the ajax to display it on the page/alert box

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0){
    $data = [];
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $data[] = array(
            "id" => $row["id_com"],
            "nick" => $row["com_nick"],
            "email" => $row["com_email"],
            "text" => $row["com_text"],
            "data" => $row["com_data"],
            "ocena" => $row["ocena"]
        );
    }
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(data);
```

js:

```
$.ajax
    ({
        url: "/commdown.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(retdata)
        {
          $.each(retdata,function(i,data){
              alert(  

                      "id: " + data.id +
                      "\nnick: " + data.nick +
                      "\nemail: " + data.email +
                      "\ntext: " + data.text +
                      "\ndata: " + data.data +
                      "\nocena: " + data.ocena

              );
            });
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        { 
            alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
        }  
    });
```

Comment: Code inside $.each doesn't work. I added two alerts. One inside success funtion is showing up, but another inside each doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

to get a proper json try this..

```
$data = array();
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
    $data[] = json_encode($row);
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Either you can use.

```
$data = $result->fetch_all( MYSQLI_ASSOC );
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: yes, edited the answer, first i mention the second way of making thinks ..